# Add rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, prefix, prepend

I am wanting to prepend parent directory to serve /child
i.e.

```
user Entered URL website.com/child
serves website.com/parent/child

child naming scheme CN-XX000 
"CN-"   static
`"XX000" dynamic (wildcard?)
```

Any/All Suggestions & Help Much Appreciated!
I am not knowledgeable re: htaccess and have not attempted any changes.

OK, so I put on my thinking cap and this is what I came up with. Does anyone see any negatives or issues? It appears to be working...

```
    # START Forward URL Campaigns
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^CN-$
    RewriteRule ^CN-$\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/dtnarecalls\.com\/Campaigns\/$1" [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
    # END Forward URL Campaigns
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "appears to be working" ... The pattern `^CN-$\/?(.*)$` won't match a requested `CN-XX000`. Also the `HTTP_HOST` won't contain  "CN-", since that is an invalid domain name (unless you are doing some freaky local experiments).